# Read Excel sheet in C#

Tags: c#, excel

Error while reading Excel sheet from C#:

> ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified

How to solve this?

This is my code:

```
     OdbcConnection oConn = new OdbcConnection();
     oConn.ConnectionString =
       "Provider=MSDASQL.1;data source=D:\\Para_Lalit\\sample.xlsx;Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;Format=xlsx'"; 
     OdbcCommand oComm = new OdbcCommand();
     oComm.Connection = oConn;
     oComm.CommandText = "Select * From [aa$]";
     try
     {
         DataSet ds = new DataSet();
         OdbcDataAdapter oAdapter = new OdbcDataAdapter(oComm);
         oConn.Open();
         oAdapter.Fill(ds);
         dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
         dataGridView1.DataBind();
         dataGridView1.DataMember = ds.Tables[0].TableName;
     }
```

Comment: if you really want to solve this, the first thing you need to do is pose a question that contains sufficient information for people to be able to answer it!

Comment: Please, add the code you are using to make the connection and the connection string you have used.

Comment: thats fine , i ll give description... thanks for suggestion sir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look for a dll called OfficeOpenXML, there is an opensource excel package you can download to manipulate Excel files